# Javascript: error getting input value the first time that the function is called

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues getting an input value with Javascript, the first time a function is called I get only the username input value. I am doing a login input form, and before all the inputs are filled I do not want to enable the login button.

**So what happens:** I double click on the input field username and the browser automatically fills username and password inputs because it has it in the memory.But the function `check_login_inputs()` gets only the value of `username` the first time. If I do again (double click and re-select the username I want to use) -> the function `check_login_inputs()` gets both the values (`username` and `password`).

My code:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#username');
input.addEventListener('input', function(){
    check_login_inputs();
});

function check_login_inputs(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    alert(username+' '+password);

    if (username.length < 1) {
        username_ok = false;
        $('#username').css('border', '3px red solid');
        document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = true;

    }else if (password.length < 1) {
        password_ok = false;
        $('#password').css('border', '3px red solid');
        document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = true;
    }else if (username.length > 1 && password.length > 1) {
        username_ok = true;
        password_ok = true;
        $('#username').css('border', '3px green solid');
        $('#password').css('border', '3px green solid');

        if (username_ok == true && password_ok == true) {
            document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = false;
        }
    }   

}
```

THE SOLUTION IS AT THE BOTTOM

Comment: Can you give a fiddle.

Comment: You can add the event listener for mouse clik and for keypress.

Comment: No I cannot make it work in fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is working:

```
function check_login_inputs(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        if(username.length < 1) {
            username_ok = false;
            $('#username').css('border', '3px red solid');
            document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = true;
        }

        if(username.length > 1) {
            username_ok = true;
            $('#username').css('border', '3px green solid');
        }
        if(password.length < 1) {
            password_ok = false;
            $('#password').css('border', '3px red solid');
            document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = true;
        }
        if(password.length > 1) {
            password_ok = true;
            $('#password').css('border', '3px green solid');
        }
        if(username_ok == true && password_ok == true) {
                document.getElementById("login_button").disabled = false;
            }
        }
```